Please synonymize [heuristics-and-biases] with [bias]
Having an additional heuristics-and-biases tag is confusing and counterproductive, since heuristics are so intimately intertwined with biases anyway.  Splitting out a separate heuristics tag would probably not make sense for the same reason.
Since we need 4+ users with a score of 5 in the bias tag for this to go through, it does not look like there are enough active voting members to put it through on its own.

it's worth noting that the term 'heuristics and biases' is most often used in reference to a particular paradigm pioneered by kahneman and tversky, due to the landmark Science publication (and later, book) by that name. Other camps, such as Gigerenzer and his 'fast and frugal heuristics' specifically use the term 'heuristics and biases' to contrast the two approaches, though both camps will use words 'heuristic' and 'bias' in the general sense. the two words individually are not synonymous, as one implies non-normativity (bias) but not necessarily a mental shortcut [...]

... whereas the other (heuristic) implies the opposite

@Jeff Duly noted.  I wasn't necessarily arguing they were identical (I'm not steeped in this literature, I was more trying to propagate this message out to the community from a few chat conversations that took place about a pending synonym), but just for the sake of tagging, this framework may keep it better organized.

Good idea; I've made the change.
